# WPF Charting - Set interval for Category Axis

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

it's been a couple of days that i'm searching for a solution to my problem but i've not been able to solve it yet.

I added a chart to my WPF C# application that shows the values of temperature for each DateTime variable. I used the DotNetProjects.WpfToolkit.DataVisualization package. I wanted to rotate the labels of the X axis by 90° and i added the following lines of code:

```
               <s:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>                 

              <s:CategoryAxis
                 Name="timeax"
                 ShowGridLines="False"
                 
                 Title="Time"                     
                 Orientation="X">
                 <s:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
                    <Style
                       TargetType="s:AxisLabel">
                       <Setter
                          Property="Template">
                          <Setter.Value>
                             <ControlTemplate
                                TargetType="s:AxisLabel">
                                <TextBlock                                     
                                   Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}">
                                   <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                      <RotateTransform
                                         Angle="-90"
                                         CenterX="40"
                                         CenterY="30" />
                                   </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                </TextBlock>
                             </ControlTemplate>
                          </Setter.Value>
                       </Setter>
                    </Style>
                 </s:CategoryAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
              </s:CategoryAxis>
              
           </s:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
```

The problem is that I'm not able to set an interval for the values in the axis and when i have too many values the result is something like that:

[image]

For the Y axis i'm able to change the interval because i added it as a LinearAxis:

```
     <s:Chart.Axes>
        <s:LinearAxis
           Orientation="Y"
           ShowGridLines="True"
           Interval="0.15"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left"
           />
     </s:Chart.Axes>
```

But i cannot do the same with the X axis because i want to rotate the labels. Any idea about how to solve my problem? thank you very very very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by changing the type of axis from CategoryAxis to DateTimeAxis. In this case there is no need to set an interval, it settles automatically on the basis of the window's size.

```
            <s:DateTimeAxis
           Orientation="X"
           Title="Time"
           >
           <s:DateTimeAxis.AxisLabelStyle>
              <Style
                 TargetType="s:AxisLabel">
                 <Setter
                    Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                       <ControlTemplate
                          TargetType="s:AxisLabel">
                          <TextBlock
                             Text="{TemplateBinding FormattedContent}">
                             <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                                <RotateTransform
                                   Angle="-90" />
                             </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                          </TextBlock>
                       </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                 </Setter>
                 <Setter
                    Property="StringFormat"
                    Value="{}{0:dd/MM/yyyy}" />
              </Style>


           </s:DateTimeAxis.AxisLabelStyle>

        </s:DateTimeAxis>
```